# How to stack a convolutional autoencoder?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoders, stacking

I am trying to figure out as to how to stack a convolutional autoencoder (CAE)?

Consider a convolutional autoencoder (CAE) (using MNIST data, 28x28 input dimensions):

```
28x28(input) -- convolve with 5 filters, each filter 5x5 -->  5 @ 28 x 28 maps -- maxPooling --> 5 @ 14 x 14 (Hidden layer, H) -- reverse-maxPool --> 5 @ 28 x 28 -- convolve with 5 filters, each filter 5x5 --> 28x28 (output)
```

I have trained such a CAE, I ran training for over 1000 iterations and error appears to reducing as the iterations progress. At the end, I checked if input == output and it was.

Now,

1. If I have to stack the CAE, I need to feed the "hidden layer" maps of current stack as "input" to next stack. Is my understanding right?
2. If (1) is true. My next stack expects one map as input however there are 5-maps in my current stack's hidden layer. How do I collapse/calculate one map from 5-hidden maps ?
3. Right now, I am doing this,
   I = max_across_all_maps(hidde layer maps) 
   Something like a "high pass filter" to collapse all hidden-layer maps to one map. Is that a valid thing to do?

Comment: How did you get your feature maps to be of dimention 28x28 shouldnt it be like 24x24 ?

Comment: @vaibhav input is zero-padded, so 28x28 -> zero padding -> 32x32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging for a few weeks, I think I found answers to my questions. I am posting it here for completeness.

1. yes
2. consider, input I=3 channels and you have F=5 filters, then in the hidden layer you have activations A = 5 maps ( 5F X 3I -> for each filter sum filter-responses over all input channels). The activations (A) are the maps that needs to be passed onto next stack as inputs
3. that is wrong, the traditional stacked-autoencoders don't do that.